# asp.NET If then inside of DIV tag?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have two menus based on someones credentials.

The menu is an UL within a wrapping DIV and I would like to place an If Then within that DIV to set is class dynamically.

Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Give the element an id and add the runat="server" attribute to it.
You can now access if from your code and set its attributes programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If its just a div, you can use asp:Panel instead -- asp:Panel will render a Div, and you can set its visibility in your code behind

Answer (score -1):

Scratch that, actually that wont work.

I need to hide a specific list item and so what I will simply do is write that list item dynamically when the correct user is logged in.

Comment: You should edit your original question and not provide additional info as an answer. Stackoverflow doesn't work as a forum.